# Retrieving custom salesforce Object in angular js application

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I have done a simple application where I could retrieve data from Salesforce predefined objects. I was getting a `recentItems` JSON array & from that JSON array, I used to render the data in html page of angular js application.

[image]

Now for custom SObjects I am following the same procedure but the recentItem array is ending up empty

[image]

Is there any other way to retrieve the data from Salesforce?

Need suggestions !

Comment: Data access for custom SObjects behaves the same as data access for standard SObjects.  Are you sure recentItems[] is not empty on the server?  If it is not empty, then you will need to add more details to your question about how you get the data from Salesforce to the angular app before someone can provide an answer.

Comment: yes once we do any CURD operations the data will be found in recentItem . In my case i was trying to retrieve from salesforce . so it was showing as empty array . Then i asked my backend team to send me JSON data as response & calling to that  i got the JSON data for my application . It got solved . Thanks for try :)